# Is it possible to change the number in an object name by using a loop?

Tags: excel, userform, multipage, vba

I have multiple pages in a userform multipage and each page has an image object. The image of page1 is named image1, the image of page2 is named image2, and so on.

I need to reference these image objects inside a loop. Is it possible to do something like `"image"&i` where `i` is the number in the image name? I tried it but I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
UserForm1.Controls ("Image" & i).Picture = LoadPicture(imageName)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it like this: `UserForm1.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Controls("Image" & i) = LoadPicture(imageName)` but I got a "Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': Could not find the specified object". What could be happening?

Comment: You should call the controls on the form itself. You don't have to reference the individual pages. I changed the answer so it calls your form

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Also, I think the picture property should be added, otherwise it doesn't work. Final code is `UserForm1.Controls ("Image" & i).Picture = LoadPicture(imageName)`. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, I changed the answer to your final code as well ;)